# Is there something I can execute via the CLI, to show the presence or absence of an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when attempting connection to a domain/URI?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

Is there anything I could I execute from a linux command line from 2 different linux clients, in 2 different locations, that may show the presence of absence of an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET message (or similar) in the output of the connection attempt? I'd like to know if there's a way I can do this when attempting the connection via either the domain or full URI using https.

(My understanding is that an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET can be an indicator that a connection is failing due to a blocking firewall. I'm trying to establish whether there's a potential blocking firewall for a resource, when using one connection path compared to another).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`curl`](https://manpages.debian.org/curl.1#EXIT_CODES) command will have an exit code of 56 when a *connection reset by peer* happens:

> 56 Failure in receiving network data.

```
curl http://someurl/
```

```
$ curl http://192.0.2.2:8080/
unfinished data...
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ echo $?
56
```

There's no guarantee (from the documentation) that 56 is only caused by *Connection reset by peer* or even that *Connection reset by peer* can only exit with 56, but one can also filter the error on *stderr* like this (`2>&1` is placed first on purpose):

```
LANG=C curl --no-progress-meter http://someurl/ 2>&1 >/dev/null |
    grep -Fq 'Connection reset by peer' && echo RST || echo non-RST
```

which would print RST for a *Connection reset by peer* and non-RST for anything else (including success).

It would be a brittle thing to use for production (this string could appear as header data etc.), but as it's for debugging a specific problem...